# Boost shared_ptr on class object

Tags: c++, class, boost, shared-ptr

Say I have the following code:

controller.hpp

```
#include "testing.hpp"
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
class controller
{
    public:
        controller(void);
        void test_func (void);
        boost::shared_ptr <testing> _testing;
}
```

controller.cpp

```
#include "controller.hpp"
controller::controller() {
    boost::shared_ptr <testing> _testing (new testing);
    std::cout << _testing->test_bool << std::endl;
}

void controller::test_func (void) {
    // how to use _testing object?
    std::cout << _testing->test_bool << std::endl;

    return;
}

int main (void) {
    controller _controller;    // constructor called
    test_func();
    return 0;
}
```

testing.hpp

```
class testing
{
    public:
        bool test_bool = true;
}
```

Am I using a `shared_ptr` properly here for a class member?  Multiple functions in class `controller` need to use the `_testing` object, and I don't want the `testing` classes' constructor / deconstructor to be called every time the pointer goes out of scope.  Maybe this cant' be avoided, I'm starting to realize.

Comment: I'd use `boost::make_shared` rather than `new`. The `.get()` is pointless the way you used it. Also, there's no variable named `_testing` in your `main()`, so that won't compile.

Comment: OK.  You're right.  I'm trying to share `_testing` to all functions in class `controller` without calling it's constructor every time.

Answer (score 1):

The testing object get constructed in controller constructor and destructed when it go out of the scope.

Just:

```
int main (void) {
    controller _controller;    // constructor called
    _controller.test_func(); 
    // destructor of controller called, because it go out of scope,
    // so testing destructor is called too because, there is no more
    // shared_ptr pointing to it!
}
```

[EDITED] To match question owner edits

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty of rewriting your code to demonstrate a usage of a shared pointer. Pretty typically it is used so an object can be in two places at once, moved around, and destruction is automatic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class testing
{
public:
    std::string str;
    testing( const char* in ) : str( in ) { }
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr <testing> SP_testing;

class controller
{
public:
    controller( const char* in );
    void test_func ( );
    SP_testing _testing;
};

controller::controller( const char* in )
    :_testing( boost::make_shared< testing >( in ) )
{
    std::cout << "controller constructor: \"" << _testing->str << '\"' << std::endl;
}

void controller::test_func (void) {
    std::cout << "test_func: \"" << _testing->str << "\"  - cnt: " << _testing.use_count( ) << std::endl;
}

int main (void)
{
    //yet to be used shared pointer
    SP_testing outsider;
    {
        //this will create an instance of testing.
        controller _controller( "this is a test" ); // constructor called, prints
        outsider= _controller._testing;             //assign shared pointer
        _controller.test_func( );                   // test called, prints usage count.

    }//leaving scope, _controller will be destroyed but the _testing it created will not

    std::cout << "outsider: \"" << outsider->str << "\"  - cnt: " << outsider.use_count( ) << std::endl;

    //now testing will get destroyed.
    return 0;
}
```

Above, 'outsider' took a pointer to `controller::_testing`. At `test_func` they both have a pointer to the same object. Even though controller create the testing object it does not get destroyed when controller gets destroyed. Very handy when these kind of situations arise. This code can be pasted into one .cpp file. Thanks to @Dan Mašek for the heads up on `make_shared`